# GET Request error, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier OPTIONS

Tags: php, javascript, http, get, xmlhttprequest

I appear to be getting a very strange error when sending a get request, I am running both the 
PHP and the javascript code on the same server, so no origin problems. Errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
OPTIONS http://localhost/Scores.php
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

on this line:

```
        req.send("&name="+username+"&pw="+password);
```

My full code:

```
function initiateLoginSequence() {
    var isnewplayer=prompt("Hello! Are you new?(Y/N)");
    if(isnewplayer == "N") {
        var username = prompt("Enter username.");
        var password = prompt("Enter Password.");
    } else {
        var username = prompt("Enter a username. This will be used for future logins.");
        var password = prompt("Enter a password. This will be used for future logins.","*");
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();  
        req.open('GET', 'http://localhost/Scores.php', true);   
        req.send("&name="+username+"&pw="+password);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably not the answer to your question. But noticed that you are calling `send()` twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
req.open('GET', 'http://69.144.34.106/Scores.php?name='+username+'&pw='+password, true);   
req.send();
```